# I want to get django rest choices key instead of Value

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**When i select choice for degree type it returns the value of the choice but i want to get key. For example when i select *UNFINISHED_BACHELOR* from choices it returns *Unfinished Bachelor's degree* but i want get *UNFINISHED_BACHELOR***

```
class CandidateEducation(models.Model):
    class DegreeType(models.TextChoices):
        HIGH_SCHOOL = "High School"
        UNFINISHED_BACHELOR = "Unfinished Bachelor's degree"
        TWO_YEAR = "Two-year degree"

    degree_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, choices=DegreeType.choices, null=True, blank=True
    )
    degree_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    institution = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

class CandidateEducationList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CandidateEducationSerializer
    queryset = CandidateEducation.objects.all()

class CandidateEducationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CandidateEducation
        fields = "__all__"

Result:
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "degree_type": "Unfinished Bachelor's degree",   ----> Error
        "degree_title": "ABC",
        "institution": "aaa",
    }
]

Expected
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "degree_type": "UNFINISHED_BACHELOR",  ---> Correct
        "degree_title": "ABC",
        "institution": "aaa",
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want them accessible outside the model, then define the choices class outside the model, then use

```
DegreeType.HIGH_SCHOOL
```

Or, if you need the text for anything

```
DegreeType.HIGH_SCHOOL.label
```

Comment: The problem is when i post data it return the value of choice. But i want to get key of the choice

Comment: Oh, I see. It's kind of designed like that - your output there is user friendly. Returning the key value would make no sense really. Only way to do that is to change the description to be the same as the key.